# Can't get onClick() call back after setStateListAnimator(null)

Tags: android, android-view, android-button, android-7.0-nougat, rippledrawable

The title is pretty self-explanatory, I have a button for which I call `setStateListAnimator(null);`. I've also registered for an `OnClickListener` callback. The problem is whenever I call `setStateListAnimator(null)` I don't get callback for `onClick()`.

```
<Button android:id="@+id/urlSubmittButton"
    android:layout_below="@id/editLyout"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:text="Add"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="5dp" />
```

and in my `Fragment`:

```
urlSubmitButton = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.urlSubmittButton);

urlSubmitButton.setClickable(true);
urlSubmitButton.setEnabled(true);
urlSubmitButton.setOnClickListener(this);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    urlSubmitButton.setStateListAnimator(null);
}
```

As you can see, I tried setting the `Button` clickable and enabled, it doesn't change the behavior. However commenting simply that line of code works the charm.

Is this intended behavior for API 24? Because so far I've only been able to reproduce this issue in API 24 device. If not, then is there any other way of stopping `stateListAnimator` which causes a water-drop-ripple-effect in `Button` when clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If not, then is there any other way of stopping `stateListAnimator` which causes a water-drop-ripple-effect in `Button` when clicked?

First of all, I don't think `stateListAnimator` is somehow connected with ripple effect. Ripple is just a background set to the `Button`, whereas `stateListAnimator` specifies what animation to perform based on the current state of the view. See states in [`StateListDrawable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html).

In order to completely hide the ripple effect apply this to the style of your activity:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
  ...
  <item name="selectableItemBackground">@null</item>
  <item name="selectableItemBackgroundBorderless">@null</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Hmm, I thought `android:animation` in a `Button` was set to ripple effect using `state_pressed` (I could be wrong ofcourse). You still haven't mentioned why regardless what stateListAnimator *actually* does nullifying it stops `onClick()` callback. I will however check the `style` and let you know if it worked.